# How to group by week/month/year and time frame 8hr/11hr/14hr/17hr/20hr in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, timestamp

I need to group 2 tables (Key = analysis_id <=> id) where my output should show the last week or month or year, grouped by a **Time range**. I have around 4000 inputs from users.

> Example of tables I have

```
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+-----+------------------------+
 | user_id  | Analyze_id  | result      |    |id    | arm |  date                  |
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+-----+------------------------+
 | 1        | 9000        | 0.753478    |    | 9000 | "R" | 2022-10-30 06:38:29    |
 | 2        | 8553        | 0.603724    |    | 8553 | "L" | 2022-10-22 11:48:42    |
 | 3        | 9886        | 0.931123    |    | 9886 | "R" | 2022-10-01 14:48:40    |
 | 4        | 4831        | 0.755645    |    | 4831 | "L" | 2022-10-01 05:18:14    |
 | 5        | 2458        | 0.662494    |    | 2458 | "R" | 2022-10-01 05:18:12    |
 +----------+-------------+-------------+    +------+-----+------------------------+
```

> Time Range:

- 8h includes 6h to 9h29
- 11h includes 9h30 to 12h29
- 14h includes 12h30 to 15h29
- 17h includes 15h30 to 18h29
- 20h includes 18h30 to 23h59

for the moment I reach to do the INNER JOIN correctly and to show the *"last week or month or year"* (of my choice) but I don't know how to group my current output in time ranges. I imagine it with GROUP BY but I don't know how to use it in these cases.
I'm really new to MySQL (started working 2 months ago). I don't know if it's possible but think I need a variable where is a push or stock of my inputs. I sow also the sub-queries but I don't know how to use them for these cases.

```
 SELECT table1_features.user_id, analysis_id, table2.arm, table1_features.result*8 AS score, 
 table2.date 
 FROM table1_features 
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1_features.analysis_id = table2.id 
 WHERE  date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 month AND table1_features.user_id = 5 
 ORDER BY date DESC
```

And the output of my query is :

```
  const outputQuery = 
    [
     {user_id: 9000, score: 6.027824, date: '2022-10-30 06:38:29', boolean: "R"},
     {user_id: 8553, score: 4.829792, date: '2022-10-22 11:48:42', boolean: "L"},
     {user_id: 9886, score: 7.448984, date: '2022-10-01 14:48:40', boolean: "R"},
     {user_id: 4831, score: 6.04516,  date: '2022-10-01 17:18:14', boolean: "L"},
     {user_id: 2458, score: 5.299952, date: '2022-10-01 21:18:12', boolean: "R"}
    ]
```

My output should look something like these, I don't know what is possible in MySQL:

```
  const result = 
    [
      //8hr time range
      [
       {user_id: 9000, score: 6.027824, date: '2022-10-30 06:38:29', boolean: "R"}
      ],
      //11hr time range
      [
       {user_id: 8553, score: 4.829792, date: '2022-10-22 11:48:42', boolean: "L"}
      ],
      //14hr time range
      [
       {user_id: 9886, score: 7.448984, date: '2022-10-01 14:48:40', boolean: "R"}
      ],
      //17hr time range
      [
       {user_id: 4831, score: 6.04516,  date: '2022-10-01 17:18:14', boolean: "L"}
      ],
      //20hr time range
      [
       {user_id: 2458, score: 5.299952, date: '2022-10-01 21:18:12', boolean: "R"}
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Was this cross-posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given data and expected result doesn't match.

> ```
> 8h  includes 6h    to 9h29
> 11h includes 9h30  to 12h29
> 14h includes 12h30 to 15h29
> 17h includes 15h30 to 18h29
> 20h includes 18h30 to 23h59
> ```

The dates '2022-10-01 05:18:14' and '2022-10-01 05:18:12' will not be part of any of the above groups.

A case might give you the expected result:

```
SELECT t1.analysis_id, 
       t2.arm, 
       t1.`result`* 8 AS score, 
       t2.`date` ,
       case 
           when  TIME(`date`) between '06:00:00' and '09:29:00' then '08h'
           when  TIME(`date`) between '09:30:00' and '12:29:00' then '11h'
           when  TIME(`date`) between '12:30:00' and '15:29:00' then '14h'
           when  TIME(`date`) between '15:30:00' and '18:29:00' then '17h'
           when  TIME(`date`) between '18:30:00' and '23:59:00' then '20h'
       end as 'time_intervals'
FROM table1_features t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.analysis_id = t2.id 
WHERE  `date` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 1 month 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/we0nIOA2

Note, I removed the condition `AND table1_features.user_id = 5` . Do not use [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)  such as DATE rename it if possible otherwise you have to use backticks

Comment: You might want to put `'08h'` for the first time interval so that you could  sort by that as well? I think the OP wants to group by `time_intervals` also? Just a couple of thoughts!

Comment: Hi thanks a lot i will try these out!! And thanks for the feedback and you are right the timestamps hours where bad i changed them :)

Comment: i don't have enought points to give you :)  !!

Comment: @Rollo, if this answer solves your problem, please accept as answer and/or upvote.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for late reply. 
Your code for the moment is adding a new column 'time_intervals' and adding an extra info (super interesting) but is not grouping them by timeRange like the expected output i show in my question

Comment: Do you think is possible to group by 'time_intervals' ?? because that is working pretty good

Comment: @Rollo yes, but you have to add  in the group by clause all the columns in the select statement or you have to use aggregate function . Check the fiddle for both examples https://dbfiddle.uk/VhrESM3e

Comment: Thans a lot. I was trying using GROUP BY and i had lot of problems.. I was checking on the web how to solve it.. I i think you did it in the good way :) 
Thanks a lot i don't have enought point to give you one

Comment: 2 more questions. 
 First: The group By is additioning all the scores is there a way to by the amount of inputs added in the group ? or a way to count the inputs in one group.. I need the average of those

Comment: @Rollo I used aggregation function like SUM or MAX for example purposes you could use any of the aggregation function that suits your need 
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: Wow the AVG is working !! 
And.. Is there a way to group by boolean aswell ? because GROUP BY time_intervals AND boolean is not working.. The average is mixing R and L in the same group :/